# How to match exact word using query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch field values `slim` and `extra slim`, If I search for `slim` I'm getting `extra slim` included documents as a result. I want to match the exact word. I used `fieldName.keyword` while querying but It did'nt work if the field has multiple words.

The query I used is

`{"query_string": {"query": "(fit:slim)" } }`

How to match only specified value using query_string?

Answer (score 2):

When looking for exact match against a field use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on `keyword` field.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "fit.keyword": "slim"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Via `query_string`**

For exact match using `query_string` wrap the string to be matched in quotes.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "fit.keyword:\"extra slim\""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Due to some requirement specification I'm using `solr` query_string syntax.I'm not supposed to use term in the query_syntax

Comment: You mean lucene query syntax

Comment: Updated answer using `query_string` as well.

Comment: No it didn't solve. Still it is matching `extra slim` included documents

Comment: My mistake, use `fit.keyword` instead of `fit`. Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried using `keyword` but for some fields having special characters like `-` it didn't  give me proper results. so I used `"default_operator":"AND" ` to match fields having multiple words(matching only `extra slim`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190805/discussion-between-nishant-saini-and-sowmya).