# Elastic search how to make query_string match Exact phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

I need query_string to only match if it is exactly the same.

According to elastic [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#)
 on query string query:

*Whitespaces are not considered operators, this means that new york city will be passed "as is" to the analyzer configured for the field. If the field is a keyword field the analyzer will create a single term new york city and the query builder will use this term in the query. If you want to query each term separately you need to add explicit operators around the terms (e.g. new AND york AND city).*

I created an index *testingindex* and added random data:

- banna af
- cd testing af
- testing cd
- af television
- testing ab

Post:

```
POST testingindex/_doc/5
{
  "name":"banna af" 
}
```

Search:

```
GET testingindex/_search?explain
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fuzziness": 0, 
            "phrase_slop": 0, 
            "default_operator": "OR", 
            "minimum_should_match": "99%", 
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "query":"(testing af) OR (banna af)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 2.0794415,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "banna af"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.8630463,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "cd testing af"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "testing cd"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "af television"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "testing ab"
        }
      }
    ]
```

If I change the operator to:

```
"default_operator": "AND",
```

I get the correct results.

But if I change the query to:

```
    "query":"(testing af) OR (banna af) OR (badfadfaf)"
```

I get no results, I still need results to come back that do match.

How can I get *cd testing af* and *banna af* be the only results returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match exact word using query\_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375365/how-to-match-exact-word-using-query-string)

Answer (score 7):

Simply wrap the terms themselves in double-quotes (which you must escape) for an exact match and remove the `minimum_should_match` property - a simplified query would look like so:

```
GET testingindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "query":"(\"testing af\") OR (\"banna af\") OR (\"badfadfaf\")"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Yielding:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.3862944,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "qmD-EWoBqkB-aMRpwfuE",
        "_score" : 1.3862944,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "banna af"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "q2D_EWoBqkB-aMRpFPtX",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "cd testing af"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I founded several answers pretty complex regarding this topic and I love your simple and pragmatic approach!